# Multiple-Question choice - TABLE for category of question?

Tags: mysql

I am working on a multiple choice question form. I am using Flask on the back-end and MySQL 5.7 as a database.

- There will be more than 1 end-user. I already made a users table but haven't work on it yet
- There are multiple questions but I only display one question at once.
- Every question have either 3 or 4 possible choices (A, B, C or A, B, C, D)
- There is always one correct answer
- **The user can filter question based on category and get stats by category (% of question answered for this category for example)**

Should I create a new table called `category` which would look like `category_id (int, primary_key), category_text (varchar(50))`?

```
CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `question_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contributor_id` int NOT NULL,
  `question_text` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `answer_a` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `answer_b` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `answer_c` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `answer_d` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `correct_answer` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`question_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! Firstly, please **always** include your version of MySQL (or whatever RDBMS/server you're using - it can be  critical for the answer and also, images are [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530) here for the reasons outlined in the link!

Comment: Thanks just updated my post.

Comment: You still have images! And I'm disturbed to see that Facebook use PHP - surely they use a plethora of languages? Also, Napoléon died at the age of 51 and not 80! :-)

Comment: Thanks again, I deleted my picture + uploaded the table info. Yes, I just came up with those fake answers to see if people were actually reading :D

Comment: I'll put together an answer tomorrow - being told I spend too much time here! :-(

Comment: You may concider another table `question_alternatives`

Comment: Didn't have time to analyse fully - check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ea98510e177861bdfd6269fb391680d5) out - might give you some ideas!